# How to not get default output from omxplayer in bash

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, python3

I am using a `bash` shell, and I am using Python's os.system() to play a wav file using `omxplayer` every single time it detects motion. I already have it to print `"Beep"` every time it detects motion, but omxplayer also has a default output every time it is run that is clogging up my logs, which is

```
Audio codec pcm_s16le channels 1 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)
```

The python code that pr=lays the sound is

```
import os
import time
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
while True:
    if MotionSensor(4).motion_detected:
        os.system("omxplayer beep-06.wav")
        print("Beep!")
        time.sleep(1)
```

How can I make omxplayer not output this message and instead just do `print("Beep!")`? I am using `nohup python3 alarm.py > alarm.out 2>&1` because this is running overnight and I am doing this via SSH, and redirecting the output to a file named `alarm.out` on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Raspbian if that matters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the relevant bit of your code. What _exact_ command are you running with `os.system()`, how _exactly_ are you using nohup? Also explain why you're using `nohup`, that seems like an odd choice.

Comment: ok, i have edited this question for more clarity

Comment: So where does `nohup` come into this? Are you just running the python script with `nohup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to see the output of a command, just redirect its standard error and standard output to `/dev/null`:

```
    os.system("omxplayer beep-06.wav >/dev/null 2>&1")
```

That will send both output and errors to `/dev/null` and you will never see them.